# Sending inline attachments with ews

Tags: .net, exchangewebservices, outlook-web-app, inline-images

I'm using EWS to send an email with inline attachement(s).

I'm use following code for it:

```
var attachment = attachments.AddFileAttachment(path);
attachment.ContentId = cid;
attachment.IsInline = true;
attachment.ContentType = "PNG/Image";
```

Html body of the message contains following fragment

```
<img src=""cid:{cid}""></img>
```

where {cid} is a value of **cid** field.

It works when I check emails with Outlook but in [OWA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlook_Web_Access) image is not show in message body.

Please suggest me right way to send mail with inline image via EWS to view in OWA.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution for that?

Answer (score 2):

The below code works for me and I can see the inline attachment in Outlook/OWA/Mobile.

Steps:

1. HTML body with placeholders for contentids
2. Replace that placeholders with the actual attachment contentids
3. Create a new attachment and set the properties inline (true) and
   contentid (actual contentid for the associated attachment)

   ```
       string attachment = "c:\\inlineattachment.png";

       // Create an e-mail message using the ExchangeService.
       EmailMessage message = new EmailMessage(ExchangeServiceObject);

       // Subject
       message.Subject = "Email with inline attachments";

       // Message body with place holder for contentid
       message.Body = "Email body with inline attachment </br> <img src=\"cid:{0}\">";
       message.Body.BodyType = BodyType.HTML;

       // Replace the place holder with contentid
       // Random GUID is used to avoid name collision for contentids 
       string newGuid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
       message.Body = string.Format(message.Body, newGuid);

       // Create a new attachment and add necessary properties to make it inline
       message.Attachments.AddFileAttachment(attachment);
       message.Attachments[message.Attachments.Count - 1].IsInline = true;
       message.Attachments[message.Attachments.Count - 1].ContentId = newGuid;

       // Add recipeint
       message.ToRecipients.Add("recipient@domain.com");

       // Send the e-mail message and save a copy.
       message.SendAndSaveCopy();
   ```