# c# - How to create a new appointment with inline attachment via ExchangeServer(EWS)?

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I want to create a new appointment and attached an inline attachment. 
I tried to use this example (even though it describes email attachments):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh532564(v=exchg.80).aspx

and also I tried to use this solution:

[Sending inline attachments with ews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8984982/sending-inline-attachments-with-ews)
but unfortunately same here, I get only red X as display.

If I set "False" on "IsInline" property so it's fine, I receive the file and can open it on doubleClick, but I need to set it to Inline..

my code:

```
  Appointment app = new Appointment(service);
    app.Subject = "Test";
    app.IsAllDayEvent = true;
     string body= @"<html>
                          <head>
                         </head>
                         <body>
                            <img width=223 height=226 id=""1"" src=""cid:cake.jpg"">
                         </body>
                         </html>";

    app.Body = new MessageBody(BodyType.HTML, body);
    string file = @"G:\cake.jpg";
    app.Attachment.AddFileAttachment("cake.jpg",file);
    app.Attachment[0].IsInline = true;
    app.Attachment[0].ContentId = "cake.jpg";
    app.RequiredAttendees.Add("example@mail.com");
    app.Save();
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Appointments,Contacts and Tasks the default bodytype is RTF so I don't think that will work you would need to do it using RTF and setting Extended properties.